# Remove Links from Posts - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

What must I do to **remove links** in posts? I have **thousand of posts**, so I can't remove them manually! Can I use javascript ? And When must I place code ?

**For example:**

> hello [google](http://google.com)

**result**

> Hello google

I use wordpress. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 4):

[Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) is a good plugin to be able to search and replace with Grep through all posts and pages.